# Invalid HANDLE from AfxBeginThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, privileges

I am writing a multi-threaded networked application, and I'm using a separate thread with a blocking socket to receive data asynchronously from the server.

When I need to shutdown the socket I use a function which checks if the receive thread is still running and if it is calls `TerminateThread` to end it as follows:

```
DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
if( GetExitCodeThread( theApp.m_hRecvThread, &dwExitCode ) && dwExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE )
     TerminateThread( theApp.m_hRecvThread, 0 );
```

However, `GetExitCodeThread` returns `FALSE`, and when polling `GetLastError()` it returns 6 (`ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`). Which suggests that I do not have the `THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION` or `THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access rights on the `m_hRecvThread` handle.

My `m_hRecvThread` handle is set when creating the thread like so:

```
m_hRecvThread = AfxBeginThread( RecvThread, hWndMainFrame );
```

This successfully creates the thread, and the thread is running fine and exhibiting expected functionality. The `TerminateThread` and `GetExitCodeThread` are being called from the same thread which created the Receive thread in the first place.

> My understanding was that when using `AfxBeginThread`, the `HANDLE` returned had `THREAD_ALL_ACCESS` access rights, is this the case, and if so, why am I still getting `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt this GetExitCodeThread( `theApp.m_hRecvThread` ....Is `m_hRecvThread` some class member or some local variable???

Comment: @Anonymous it's a member variable of my global `theApp` variable. I have checked it's value in the debugger and it is the same as when the thread was initialized, so this is not an issue.

Comment: It is unclear how this code can compile, AfxBeginThread returns a CWinThread*, not a HANDLE.  Using TerminateThread is very unwise, short from the very nasty effects on held locks, it also leaks the thread stack.

Comment: @HansPassant I misread the function prototype for `AfxBeginThread`, for some bizarre reason I thought it returned a `CWinThread` object rather than a pointer! `HANDLE` is a typedef of `void*` which is why the implicit conversion works. Thanks! However, do you have any suggestions of what I should do instead of `TerminateThread`?

Comment: Ask nicely for the thread to stop, use an event.  Close the socket if it is buried in a system call.

Answer (score 0):

The thread created using:

```
m_hRecvThread = AfxBeginThread( RecvThread, hWndMainFrame )
```

will return a pointer to winthread. But `GetExitCodeThread()` requires the handle to the thread for example, you can pass `RecvThread->m_hThread`, which will solve the issue